# Script to delete one alphabet from XML file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I would like to delete one symbol "&" from hundred XML file's regularly. Instead of doing manual work, I want to write a .bat script and to schedule it. so that when this bat script runs, the & symbol from all the XML files has to be deleted by the script.

We have a location say D:\Transfer\, in this location my application will generate XML files regularly. I want to search for the symbol (&) in one line of XML and delete that & symbol from XML.

Can someone please help me to get out from this?

Comment: Are you aware that if you remove the "&" symbol from your XML and you have any special symbols like `<` ( `&lt;` ) or `"` ( `&quot;` ) you will end up with very confusing text or even potentially broken XML?

Comment: Hi Glenatron, We will have & symbol in one line of the entire file. So, it will be not be confusion for us.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
@echo off &setlocal
set "search=&"
set "replace="

FOR %%a IN ("D:\Transfer\*.html") DO call:process "%%~a"
goto:eof

:process
set "textfile=%~1"
set "newfile=%~1.new"
(for /f "delims=" %%i in ('findstr /n "^" "%textfile%"') do (
    set "line=%%i"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set "line=!line:%search%=%replace%!"
    echo(!line!
    endlocal
))>"%newfile%"
goto:eof
```

---

you can also use [sed](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm) for this:

```
for %%a in (*.html) do sed "y/&/ /" "%%~a" > "%%~na.new"
```

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
- <p0:InvoiceRequest xmlns:p0="http://cce.com/xi/SRM/Invoicing/global">
- <MessageHeader>
  <ID schemeID="XML">READSOFT</ID> 
 <p0:BASISPONumber>T&E</p0:BASISPONumber> 
- <Price> This is my XML file and I want to delete & symbol from this line <p0:BASISPONumber>T&E</p0:BASISPONumber> 
This file is in F:\Transfer\Transfer_out\ location in server.

Comment: please add code by editing your answer. Code in the comment box is unreadable.